# Password protect application

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

> ⚠️ I'm a n00b in openshift

For the project that I'm working on, I'm trying to password protect a node application behind a proxy.

[image: schema]

Here's the template that I'm using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: next.js app config
parameters:
  - name: CLIENT
    description: The name of the client owning the project
    required: true
  - name: PROJECT
    description: The project name
    required: true
  - name: PART
    description: The part of the project (i.e. cockpit, app, mobile, server, …)
    required: true
  - name: PROJECT_NAME
    description: The name of the ******* project to add the project to
    required: true
  - name: IMAGE_NAME
    description: The name of the image on the ******* registery
    required: true
  - name: HOSTNAME
    description: The hostname on which the project should be deployed to
    required: true
  - name: DEPLOY_PATH
    description: The path to which the project should be deployed to
    value: ""
  - name: ENVIRONMENT
    description: The environment of this project version
    value: staging
  - name: PORT
    description: The port on which the container will run
    value: "3000"
objects:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: DeploymentConfig
    metadata:
      name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
      labels:
        app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        customer: ${CLIENT}
        environment: ${ENVIRONMENT}
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 3
      selector:
        app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        customer: ${CLIENT}
        deploymentconfig: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
      strategy:
        activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
        resources: {}
        rollingParams:
          intervalSeconds: 1
          maxSurge: 25%
          maxUnavailable: 25%
          timeoutSeconds: 600
          updatePeriodSeconds: 1
        type: Rolling
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
            customer: ${CLIENT}
            environment: ${ENVIRONMENT}
            deploymentconfig: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
              image: >-
                docker-registry.default.svc:5000/${PROJECT_NAME}/${IMAGE_NAME}
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
              ports:
                - containerPort: ${{PORT}}
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 100m
                  memory: 128Mi
                requests:
                  cpu: 50m
                  memory: 64Mi
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
            - env:
              - name: BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME
                  value: admin
                - name: BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD
                  value: password
                - name: FORWARD_PORT
                  value: ${PORT}
                - name: FORWARD_HOST
                  value: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}.********
              image: xscys/nginx-sidecar-basic-auth
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}-proxy
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8000
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 100m
                  memory: 128Mi
                requests:
                  cpu: 50m
                  memory: 64Mi
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      test: false
      triggers:
        - imageChangeParams:
            containerNames:
              - ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
            from:
              kind: ImageStreamTag
              name: ${IMAGE_NAME}
              namespace: ${PROJECT_NAME}
          type: ImageChange
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}-SERVICE
      labels:
        app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        customer: ${CLIENT}
        environment: ${ENVIRONMENT}
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: 8000-tcp
          port: {8000}
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 8000
      selector:
        app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        customer: ${CLIENT}
        deploymentconfig: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
      sessionAffinity: None
      type: ClusterIP
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}-ROUTE
      labels:
        app: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}
        customer: ${CLIENT}
        environment: ${ENVIRONMENT}
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    spec:
      host: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}.***********
      path: "/"
      port:
        port: 8000               
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8000
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}-SERVICE
        weight: 100
      wildcardPolicy: None
```

I'm using this Docker image [xsc/nginx-sidecar-basic-auth](https://github.com/xsc/nginx-sidecar-basic-auth), that use Nginx as a proxy and build on top of it.

Not sure what am I doing wrong here (maybe the route), but the main route always redirects me directly to node application instead of the proxy

- update1: I thought with automatic redeployment the services and routes, previously created, would be automatically updated, but this is not possible. I'll try deleting them to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`port: {8000}` in the Service configuration doesn't look right. Why the curly brackets?

Otherwise, it appears that a request will go into a loop because the proxy will forward it to the Route, which will send it to the proxy via the Service, and again, and again. Reason being is that

```
- name: FORWARD_HOST
  value: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}.********
```

points to the `host` of the Route:

```
host: ${CLIENT}-${PROJECT}-${ENVIRONMENT}-${PART}.***********
```

(assuming the masking is for the same host in both cases)

I would suggest to set

```
- name: FORWARD_HOST
  value: localhost
```

to have the proxy forward requests to the application in a container the same pod.